# WSL Ubuntu - No change on executing chmod

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Ubuntu bash on Windows 10 and am experiencing a problem with the chmod command.I'm trying to change the permission of a file I created in ubuntu with the following path:

```
devenv@XXXXXX:/mnt/c/mykeys/amo_dev$ ls -rtl
cdtotal 8
-rwxrwxrwx 1 devenv devenv 1464 Jun 17 10:06 amo_dev.ppk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 devenv devenv 1675 Jul 30 18:26 amo_dev.pem
devenv@XXXXXX:/mnt/c/mykeys/amo_dev$ sudo chmod 600 amo_dev.pem
[sudo] password for devenv:
devenv@XXXXXX:/mnt/c/mykeys/amo_dev$ ls -lrt
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx 1 devenv devenv 1464 Jun 17 10:06 amo_dev.ppk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 devenv devenv 1675 Jul 30 18:26 amo_dev.pem
devenv@XXXXXX:/mnt/c/mykeys/amo_dev$ uname  -a
Linux NCS-100619GM01 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #706-Microsoft Mon Apr 01 18:13:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
devenv@XXXXXX:/mnt/c/mykeys/amo_dev$ cat /etc/os-release*
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: You can't chmod on the mounted system filesystem. It's not a "real" filesystem. You can only do that inside the WSL environment (everything but `/mnt/*`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610256/chmod-wsl-bash-doesnt-work . To allow chmod to work on DrvFS filesystems, they need to be mounted with the `metadata` option.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick :  this stackoverflow.com/questions/46610256/chmod-wsl-bash-doesnt-work . works...

Comment: How to add this command in my .bash_profile to get it permanent.

Comment: @BalaB Try the answer that says to edit `/etc/wsl.conf`. That doesn't require editing .bash_profile.

Comment: I don't find wsl.conf. so can I create a file with the entry?

Comment: @BalaB Yes, create it if necessary. After that, you'll need to terminate the running WSL instance (run the Windows command `wslconfig /t Ubuntu`) and then enter it again (with `wsl` or `bash`) to have the settings in `/etc/wsl.conf` take effect.